Is there a Terminal command to run the Confetti reaction/effect in a video call?
Is there a Terminal command to run the Confetti reaction/effect in a video call?
Or maybe AppleScript?
https://support.apple.com/en-us/105117

Why not make an Automator action to select the effect from the menu and then call it from the shell with open or osascript ?

I don't know how to click the green video menu bar icon. It disappears, reappears, and changes position depending on the number of menu bar items. Do you have an idea on how to open it immediately?

If you are open to using a 3rd party tool, this can be done via Raycast:
https://twitter.com/raycastapp/status/1691464764516343808

I want confetti for video calls, reactions, and not a simple animation on screen.
